# csv file Japanese characters got junk while I download in windows system

Tags: javascript, angularjs, csv, character-encoding

**Html**

```
<button class="btn btn-raised btn-inverse btn-sm" charset="shift_jis" add-bom="true" ng-csv="getSampleData" csv-header="['コード','勘定科目名','Main_code']" filename="{{ samplefilename }}.csv" field-separator="{{separator}}" decimal-separator="{{decimalSeparator}}" ><span translate> load.common.sample </span> </button>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.csv = {
     content: null,
     header: true,
     headerVisible: true,
     separator: ',',
     separatorVisible: true,
     result: null,
     encodingVisible: true,
     uploadButtonLabel: "upload a csv file"
   };

$scope.samplefilename = "Sample Support Code List"

$scope.getSampleData = [{コード: 'code _1',勘定科目名: '勘定科目名',Main_code:'maincode1'},{コード: 'code_2',勘定科目名: 'name_2', Main_code: 'Miancode2'}];
```

While downloading csv file in Ubuntu or in Mac, Japanese characters looks good, while downloading it in windows system data(Japanese data) gets junk

here is the screenshot of junk data

[image]

Comment: Did you verify that the file is wrong or it is just Excel do not use UTF-8 as default encoding?

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi  Excel do not use UTF-8

Comment: Adding BOM mark seem to help. But as you can find here (in SO), the only safe and automatic way is to encode it with UTF-16 (with BOM). This works with Excel and most of other tools. Or you should tell people to import the file, and selet the UTF-8 code (which is strange and at very end of the long list)

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Already tried with UTF-16 and BOM, but It does not work, Please give another solution

Comment: How did you it? Add to the question what did you try.

Comment: Use Excel's text import wizard. Answer the question about character encoding (which might be overly helpfully described as origin) correctly.

Answer (score 0):

**In this issue the main problem is that Japanese characters are not supported UTF-8 encoding so you have to create file with shift_jis encoding.**

filename = "filename_123.csv"

## Here main_array is collection of header's data and all rows data

CSV.open("#{Rails.root}/public/FOLDER_NAME/#{filename}", "w", encoding: params[:encoding]) do |csv|
  main_array.each do |array|
    csv << array
  end
end

csv = CSV.read("#{Rails.root}/public/FOLDER_NAME/#{filename}", encoding: params[:encoding])

csv = CSV.read("#{Rails.root}/public/FOLDER_NAME/#{filename}",encoding: params[:encoding], headers:true)

File.write("#{Rails.root}/public/FOLDER_NAME/#{filename}", csv, encoding: params[:encoding])

files << "#{filename}"

send_file "#{Rails.root}/public/FOLDER_NAME/#{filename}", filename:ERB::Util.url_encode("#{filename}") , :type => "application/csv; charset= #{params[:encoding] =='shift_jis' ? 'shift_jis' : 'UTF-8' }"